# How to validate an IP address format?

Tags: functions, expression-test, internet

Is it possible to validate the format of an IP address (say v4)?

I assumed that `IPAddress` could do this by failing on non-IP inputs but instead one can pass arbitrary strings (and other expressions), eg `IPAddress["not-an-IP"]`.

I'm thinking of analogs of python ipaddress.ip_address and ip_network that raise errors if the input is not valid format.

Alternatively is there a handy regex, ideally to also considers CIDR ranges?

Comment: Have you seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36760050)?

Comment: Thanks J.M., that looks usable.

Answer (score 2):

There might be other ways, but `Interpreter["IPAddress"]["www.example.com"]` was the first thing that came to mind.

Answer (score 0):

I have used the following in my personal "network functions" package

```
ConvertIpv4AddressToList::usage="convert from string to list";
ConvertIpv4AddressToList[ipAddress_String] := ToExpression@StringSplit[ipAddress, "."];


Ipv4AddressQ::usage="check if an IPv4 address is in the valid format";
Ipv4AddressQ[ipAddress_String] :=
    Module[
      {decimalNumbers},
      decimalNumbers = ConvertIpv4AddressToList[ipAddress];
      And[
        StringContainsQ[ipAddress, __ ~~ "." ~~ __ ~~ "." ~~ __ ~~ "." ~~ __],
        StringRiffle[decimalNumbers, "."] == ipAddress, (* eg make 1.1.1.01 fail *)
        Length@decimalNumbers == 4,
        Max[decimalNumbers] <= 255,
        Min[decimalNumbers] >= 0,
        VectorQ[decimalNumbers, IntegerQ]
      ]
    ];
```

Comment: Be careful with ToExpression, `Ipv4AddressQ @  "Abort[]"`. You could start with `Ipv4AddresQ[ ipAddress_String ? (StringMatchQ[(DigitCharacter | ".") ..]) ] :=`

Comment: Good idea thanks